# Invalid syntax error in simple Python-3 program

Tags: python, syntax, python-3.x, syntax-error

```
from TurtleWorld import *
import math

bob = Turtle()
print(bob)

draw_circle(turtle, r):
    d = r*2
    c = d*math.pi
    degrees = 360/25
    length = c // 25
    for i in range(25):
        fd(turtle, length)
        rt(turtle, degrees)

draw_circle(bob, 25)

wait_for_user()
```

---

The problem in on line 7:

> draw_circle(turtle, r):

The compiler only tells me that there is a syntax error and highlights the colon at the
end of that line.
I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but the code looks right to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in python, we define functions using the `def` keyword.. like

```
def draw_circle(turtle, r):
    # ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write:

```
def draw_circle(turtle, r):
```

to [define a function](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Your missing the def part?

Answer (score 0):

I thought, just in case the other three answers weren't obvious enough, I should tell you that you need def first

```
def draw_circle(turtle, r):
```

@People duplicating:
Seriously, could we get 1 more answer? I believe 3 (4 if you add me) isn't enough